# Program doesn't execute anything after "Calculating..."

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is a segment of a program that I made to calculate the processing power of a computer. This particular segment is meant to find the bottleneck in the system. I can provide the rest of the code if necessary. The numbers at the beginning (cpus, gpus, rams, hds) are scores for each part. When this code is executed, nothing happens after the "Calculating..." message. Please be gentle, I'm really new to this

```
from termcolor import colored
global cpus
global gpus
global rams
global hds
global type
global typ

cpus = 3.0406
gpus = 1.9893
rams = 0.8817
hds = 1.0364
type = 2
typ = 2

def btlcalc1():
  print(colored("Calculating bottleneck...", "yellow"))
  global bgpus
  global brams
  global bhds
  global bcpus
  if type == "1": #laptop
    bgpus = gpus*3.5
    brams = rams*4
    bhds = hds*5
    bcpus = cpus*2
    btlcalc2()
  if type == "2": #desktop
    btlscore = (gpus*1.75)+(rams*4)+(hds*5)+(cpus*2)
    bgpus = gpus*1.75
    brams = rams*4
    bhds = hds*5
    bcpus = cpus
    btlcalc2()
def btlcalc2():
  if bgpus <= brams and bgpus <= bhds and bgpus <= bcpus:
    gpub = 1
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if bcpus <= brams and bcpus <= bhds and bcpus <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 1
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if brams <= bcpus and brams <= bhds and brams <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 1
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if bhds <= brams and bhds <= bcpus and bhds <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 1
    btlcalc3()
def btlcalc3():
  if gpub == 1:
    print(colored("Your GPU is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your GPU score by overclocking or replacing your GPU.", "orange"))
    thanks()
  if cpub == 1:
    print(colored("Your CPU is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your CPU score by overclocking or replacing your CPU.", "orange"))
    thanks()
  if ramb == 1:
    print(colored("Your RAM is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your RAM score by overclocking, replacing, or installing more or faster RAM.", "orange"))
    thanks()
  if hdb == 1:
    print(colored("Your boot disk is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    if typ == 1:
      print(colored("You could improve your boot disk score by replacing your HDD with a faster HDD or an SSD, or by freeing up space.", "orange"))
      thanks()
    if typ == 2:
      print(colored("You could improve your boot disk score by freeing up space.", "orange"))
      thanks()

btlcalc1()
def thanks():
  print("Done")
```

EDIT: I fixed it. Modified code if anyone wants it.

```
def btlcalc1():
  print(colored("Calculating bottleneck...", "yellow"))
  global bgpus
  global brams
  global bhds
  global bcpus
  if type == 1: #laptop
    bgpus = gpus*3.5
    brams = rams*4
    bhds = hds*5
    bcpus = cpus*2
    print("Step 1 executed succesfully.")
    btlcalc2()
  if type == 2: #desktop
    btlscore = (gpus*1.75)+(rams*4)+(hds*5)+(cpus*2)
    bgpus = gpus*1.75
    brams = rams*4
    bhds = hds*5
    bcpus = cpus
    btlcalc2()
def btlcalc2():
  global gpub
  global cpub
  global ramb
  global hdb
  if bgpus <= brams and bgpus <= bhds and bgpus <= bcpus:
    gpub = 1
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if bcpus <= brams and bcpus <= bhds and bcpus <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 1
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if brams <= bcpus and brams <= bhds and brams <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 1
    hdb = 0
    btlcalc3()
  if bhds <= brams and bhds <= bcpus and bhds <= bgpus:
    gpub = 0
    cpub = 0
    ramb = 0
    hdb = 1
    btlcalc3()
def btlcalc3():
  if gpub == 1:
    print(colored("Your GPU is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your GPU score by overclocking or replacing your GPU.", "yellow"))
    thanks()
  if cpub == 1:
    print(colored("Your CPU is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your CPU score by overclocking or replacing your CPU.", "yellow"))
    thanks()
  if ramb == 1:
    print(colored("Your RAM is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    print(colored("You could improve your RAM score by overclocking, replacing, or installing more or faster RAM.", "yellow"))
    thanks()
  if hdb == 1:
    print(colored("Your boot disk is the bottleneck in your system.", "yellow"))
    if typ == 1:
      print(colored("You could improve your boot disk score by replacing your HDD with a faster HDD or an SSD, or by freeing up space.", "yellow"))
      thanks()
    if typ == 2:
      print(colored("You could improve your boot disk score by freeing up space.", "yellow"))
      thanks()
```

Comment: Perfect time for you to learn to use a debugger to step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
type = 2
...
if type == '2'
```

Integers do not equal strings. Since no condition evaluates and you don't have an "else" block, the code ends.

Adding some print debugging statements into your conditions and adding an "else" to see if that is triggering when you think a conditional should are good debugging steps.

You should read up about type casting as a way to make sure this doesn't happen in a scenario where you don't control the inputs